# Problem with admin login after deployment

Tags: mysql, permissions

I made a site for a friend and everything worked so far on my development box that we can start final deployment and testing so I decided to put it on the hosting.

So I done the standard procedure to deploy:

1. backup the database to an sql script changed the db name and stuff to corespond to the host db name, replaced the links to correspond to the host address
2. Restored the script and the db looks fine. From what I can tell trough the PhPMyAdmin
3. changed the wp-config file to the correct data

The page looks fine everything seems to work.

Except that now I can't login to the admin site anymore
when I type in the wp-admin.php it shows up but when I type in the login data and press login it goes blank :S

Firebug dosent show up any error or something.

All files have the permitions of 0644 and Folders 0755 (So default when the files get uploaded).

you can try login with any username/password to see the result but if you need I give people that can help username and password over private messages.

[Link to the site](http://www.nataliazubova.com/test/)

Anyone got any idea to what might be the problem?

Thanks for help

EDIT: Hmm looks like something wrong with jQuery. Cos I get:
$ is not a function in 2 scripts but they are my custom scripts and not the WP-core stuff

Comment: Btw: »Butifull building in the centre of Wienna« should be »The state opera - a beautiful building in the center of Vienna« ;)

Comment: Testing stuff :)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect either the culprit is one of the plugins or the theme you are using.

so, try:

-deactivating ALL plugins temporarily to narrow down the problem. If the problem goes away, activate them individually (one-by-one) to find the problematic plugin.
If you don't have access to your admin area, try deactivating plugins [manually](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_to_deactivate_all_plugins_when_not_able_to_access_the_administrative_menus.3F) via FTP or phpMyAdmin. 
-If that does not help, try switching to the unedited default theme (that came with your version of WP) for a moment by renaming your current theme's folder in wp-content/themes. The idea is to force WordPress to fall back to the default theme to rule out any theme-specific issue. 
If you don't have access to your admin area, then access your server via FTP or SFTP or whatever file management application your host provides.

-if above steps do not help, this codex guide has more information: http://codex.wordpress.org/Login_Trouble

Answer (score 1):

Based on your edit, this is a problem either with your theme or one of the plugins you use.

WordPress, by default, loads jQuery in [`noConflict()` mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).  This is to prevent stepping over other libraries that depend on `$` being a shortcut to their own internal objects.  As a result, `$` is undefined in a properly-built WordPress site.

The admin interface depends heavily on jQuery.  So if you have a plugin or theme `enqueue()`ing their own versions of jQuery *not* in `noConflict()` mode, you'll get a conflict and some collisions.

So, disable your theme and plugins by [deactivating them manually via FTP](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_to_deactivate_all_plugins_when_not_able_to_access_the_administrative_menus.3F) and reload the admin site.

Then, activate your plugins 1 by 1 until you find the one that broke the site.

If the site's still working, activate your theme.

After you figure out which system it was breaking things, track down the developer and smack them for me.